# Android calendar view date color

Tags: android, date, colors, calendarview

I have a list of dates that I want to color in red on calendarview .
how can I do ?

my activity..

```
public class Calendario extends Activity {

    RelativeLayout rl;
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    CalendarView cal;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calendar);

        rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);
        cal = new CalendarView(Calendario.this);

        rl.addView(cal);
        cal.setOnDateChangeListener(new OnDateChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    }


}
```

What code i've to add in order to color a date ?

Comment: There a few styling methods on the CalendarView class i.e. setSelectedWeekBackgroundColor() are you trying to change the colour of the selected date?

Comment: this method changes the whole week , I want change the color of a single date,as sunday in a normal calendar

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet might be to create your own CalendarView class i.e. CalendarViewCustom based on the source code found [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/CalendarView.java).

You could then add an extra method to the LegacyCalendarViewDelegate class similar to the setFocusedMonthDateColor() method to iterate through the weeks and set a date and colour in the WeekView class (might be worth storing these key/value date/colours as an Map collection instance variable in the WeekView class). e.g.

```
public void setMonthDateColor(Date date, int color) {                
    final int childCount = mListView.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        WeekView weekView = (WeekView) mListView.getChildAt(i);
        if (weekView.isDateInWeek(date)) {
            //this method adds the date and colour to a 
            //Map collection in weekView Object 
            weekView.setDateColour(date, color);
        }
    }
}
```

The above method then needs to be exposed by adding another method to the parent class CalendarViewCustom (similar to its existing methods) which can then be called on an instance of the class i.e.

```
public int setMonthDateColor(Date date, int color) {
    return mDelegate.getMonthDateColor(date, color);
}
```

All you need to do then is draw the listed colours on the canvas in the WeekView class method called drawWeekNumbersAndDates() for the specified dates using the existing for loop ( for (; i < nDays; i++) ) and iterate over the Map and change the paint colour for the date text i.e. mMonthNumDrawPaint.setColor().

Hope this points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Hope this helps

```
android:weekDayTextAppearance="@style/CalendarWeekDateText"


<style name="CalendarWeekDatText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android:theme="@style/testTheme"
```

Use this theme or a custom theme which has parent as this theme.

To make it white

To Choose other than white change the color use the following

```
android:textColorPrimary="@color/yourColor"
```

for other text colors use the following

```
android:weekDayTextAppearance="@style/weekDayTextAppearance"
    android:dateTextAppearance="@style/appTextAppearance"
    android:unfocusedMonthDateColor="@color/colorLoginBtn"
    android:selectedWeekBackgroundColor="@color/colorLoginBtn"
    android:weekSeparatorLineColor="@color/colorLoginBtn"
    android:focusedMonthDateColor="@color/colorLoginBtn"
    android:weekNumberColor="@color/colorLoginBtn"
```