# How do I add static events in a calendar-view in android studio?

Tags: android, calendar

I am building a simple schedule app and added a calendar using calendar view. I want to add events to some particular dates as Holiday and mark them with red color (Just the dates to be red). Eg- Every Saturday and Sunday will be red in color and some other days as well. So basically what i am asking for is that how do I make a calendar with events that can only be changed by the developer. I am a beginner in android studio so please try to answer in the simplest way you can answer.

Answer (score 1):

In order to add events and mark color to a date, you need to create your own custom calendar view, the default calendar view does not provide enough function to do that, you may want to look at this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26997042/android-calendar-view-date-color)