# Highlight dates in CalendarView

Tags: java, android, calendarview

How can I change color of specific date of CalendarView? I am creating simple app that can add event on calendar and I want to highlight dates which has events. Can anyone tell how it can be done or if it is not possible, suggest me some other way.

Answer (score 2):

The way to achieve this is by creating a CustomCalenderView view class which extends from CalenderView.

In that CustomCalenderView class create a new method that would take care of changing the color of the calender date you want to change colour of.

Something like this.

```
public void setMonthDateColor(Date date, int color) {                
    final int childCount = mListView.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        WeekView weekView = (WeekView) mListView.getChildAt(i);
        if (weekView.isDateInWeek(date)) {
            //this method adds the date and colour to a 
            //Map collection in weekView Object 
            weekView.setDateColour(date, color);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public int setMonthDateColor(Date date, int color) {
    return mDelegate.getMonthDateColor(date, color);
}
```

Ref:[more details on creating a custom Calender View](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27036651/13533028)